# After i upgrade grails from 2.3.7 to 2.4.3, all request.JSON data is break down.

Tags: grails, encoding, character-encoding, request

Here is one of my save method.

def domainInstance = new Domain(request.JSON)

domainInstance.save()

...

Before i upgrade Grails version, i could save Korean OR other languages to DB without any encoding problems.
After upgrading Grails to 2.4.3, all AJAX input data that is saved with request.JSON display like this. 
������������

(i also checked the database, but it was saved like above)

However, all other language data that is requested with params(form), it is save as it is.

i checked all config(grails.converters.encoding), request header's content- type, GSP page's charset values, however, everything was set properly.(UTF-8)

So, i tested like below

def data = request.reader.text

log.debug  data

log.debug request.getCharacterEncoding()  --> print out utf-8

def bindingData = JSON.parse(data)        --> print out the same data as inputted

def domainInstance = new Domain(bindingData ) --> when i checked db, data is saved properly

because of this, i think JSON.parse(request) method might have problem.

but the crazy thing is this only occur at deployed linux server.

it won't occur at local environment.

i hope somebody give me good advice

i am so tired of this problem.

here is the list of plugins i upgraded for your information.

```
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.7'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"

    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.8"

    test ":code-coverage:2.0.3-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

it's me again. 
Tomcat setting cause this problem. 
After i changed locale configuration, it is working properly.
However, i still do not understand how the tomcat works with the previous setting and grails 2.3.7.
Anyway, i hope this post is helpful whomever having similar problems.